# React - Apollo Client query with input variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm struggling understanding how to query stuff with apollo client in react.

This is the query id like to achieve:

```js
query signIn {
  signIn(input: { email: "test2@gmail.com", password: "test123" }) {
    token
  }
}
```

I'd like to save all my queries into a queries folder, so here's what I did:

```js
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const SIGN_IN = gql`
  {
    signIn(input: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

And I'm calling my query inside the homepage like so:

```js
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { SIGN_IN } from '../../apollo/queries/SIGN_IN';

export const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(SIGN_IN, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        email: 'test3@gmail.com',
        password: 'test123',
      },
    },
  });
```

But I end-up getting this error:

```js
{
  "loading": false,
  "error": {
    "graphQLErrors": [],
    "networkError": {
      "name": "ServerError",
      "response": {},
      "statusCode": 400,
      "result": {
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Variable \"$email\" is not defined.",
            "locations": [
              {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 25
              },
              {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 1
              }
            ],
            "extensions": {
              "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
              "exception": {
                "stacktrace": [
                  "GraphQLError: Variable \"$email\" is not defined.",
```

How should I do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the answer

If anyone's looking for this, here it goes:

```js
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const SIGN_IN = gql`
  query SIGN_IN($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    signIn(input: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query definition should be like this:

```
export const SIGN_IN = gql`
 query signIn($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    signIn(input: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
      token
    }
  }
;
```